# Would this question be appropriate

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I study ISO 2700x and its implications, for example how organizations must meet requirements regarding storage of "e-mail (address) lists". For example the term "e-mail list" would mean a list of electronic mails (distinct from the addresses) but isn't is also a difference between the "mail" and the actual letter? If I understand correctly the word "e-mail" was not supposed to mean the actual letter being sent but the way of transmitted it, similar to the difference between the mail (the system) and the letter (what is being delivered) before 1971 when the first e-mail letter was being sent.

What I also want to know in this context is how you legally write a list according to laws and GDPR and ISO, if a list can contain only one element and if the empty list is also a list in the legal definition of an "e-mail list".

Comment: Legal questions don't belong here, they go in [legal.se], so the GDPR and general legal part would be off topic. Complying with standards are off topic over in Legal, so the ISO part of your question would be off topic there. Also keep in mind that different bodies have different definitions.  If you want both definitions and the security or legal implications around these definitions, you might want to ask in both places.